# c++ Memory Management Buddy System Weird Memory Address Issue

Tags: memory, c++11

I am attempting to implement a buddy memory system using c++, but I am running into some issues. I assign a memory address to an element in an array, and the memory address that is stored in main is different than the one returned by the function. I believe there is an error when the address is stored, resetting it to a "valid" position, but i'm not sure which one is the "correct" address. Code and input are posted below.

```
void buddy_manager(memoryNode* root, process* processes, int num){
    int i = 0, count = 0, removed = 0, j = 0;
    process running[num];
    while(removed < 5){ 
    if(i % 50 == 0 && count<5){ 
        cout << "Adding process: " << count << endl;
        running[count] = processes[count];
        running[count].space = my_malloc(root, running[count].memory * 1000);
        printf("Made new node @ %p \n", running[count].space);
        count++;
     }
     //Check to remove the process from the list omitted

}

char* my_malloc (memoryNode* root, int size) {
    //If there are child nodes and the current node is not occupied, visit them!
    if(root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL && root->occupied == 0){
            if(my_malloc(root->left, size) == NULL){
                my_malloc(root->right, size);   
            }
    } else{ //we are at a leaf node
        if(root->max_size >= size && root->max_size/2 < size && root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL && root->occupied == 0){ //if the node is good for insertion{
            printf("address of new node: %p with slize: %d and element size: %d \n", root->start, root->max_size, size);
            root->occupied = 1;
            return root->start;
        } else if(!(root->max_size > size && root->max_size/2 < size) && root->max_size > 0 && root->occupied == 0 && root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) { //Grow the tree
            root->left = new memoryNode(root->start, root->max_size/2, NULL, NULL, 0); 
            root->right = new memoryNode((char*)(root->start + (root->max_size)/2), root->max_size/2, NULL, NULL, 0);
            //printf("Made new nodes at %p and %p \n", root->left->start, root->right->start);
            my_malloc(root->left, size);
        } else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
address of new node: 0xb6d86008 with size: 156250 and element size: 94000 
Made new node @ 0xb6d86008 
Adding process: 1
address of new node: 0xb6dd24bc with size: 312500 and element size: 193000 
Made new node @ 0xb6dd2400 
Adding process: 2
address of new node: 0xb6e1e970 with size: 156250 and element size: 106000 
Made new node @ 0xb6e1e900 
Adding process: 3
address of new node: 0xb6dc8c25 with size: 39062 and element size: 26000 
Made new node @ 0xb6dc8c00 
Adding process: 4
address of new node: 0xb6e44bca with size: 19531 and element size: 18000 
Made new node @ 0xb6e44b00
```

A you can see, the first node is fine, but the rest of the nodes end up getting reset to 00 for their last two digits.

Comment: What is the data type of `running[count].space` and `root->start`?

Answer (score 1):

**A wild guess, if you're using a 32-bit system:**

The size of your `process` structure is not a multiple of 4 bytes. So the `space` field in the second element of your `process running[num]` array is not properly aligned to a 4-byte address.

Adding `4-sizeof(process)%4` bytes at the end of this structure should solve the problem.

---

**A wild guess, if you're using a 64-bit system:**

The size of your `process` structure is not a multiple of 8 bytes. So the `space` field in the second element of your `process running[num]` array is not properly aligned to an 8-byte address.

Adding `8-sizeof(process)%8` bytes at the end of this structure should solve the problem.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you have verified that the issue above is not the reason behind the problem, then print `root->start` before returning it from function `my_malloc`, and make sure that it's **always** aligned to 4 (or 8) bytes.

I've also noticed that function `my_malloc` doesn't return a value in all cases, which might be leading to undefined behavior (I don't understand how you managed to compile it without an error to begin with).

So inside this function, add `return` before `my_malloc(root->left, size)`.

Comment: I believe you are correct that the element is not properly aligned, but I checked the sizeof(running[count]), and it came out to 16 bytes.

Comment: How can I ensure it is aligned to a 4 byte addressed? It is indeed not correctly aligned when it is returned.

Comment: @jtrevag: It's hard to say, because you have not specified the `memoryNode` constructor, but it looks like there's a good chance that the problem is in `new memoryNode((char*)(root->start + (root->max_size)/2), ...)`.

Comment: I was able to fix my memory addresses. When I malloc'ed space for the whole set of nodes, I was using 10000000 instead of 10240000. So when the nodes were being split, they were going to weird offset addresses. Now everything is working as intended. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It turns out things are still not working as intended, unfortunately. You are right where the problem is, but I am still unsure how to fix it.